# Load report failed when implementing crystal report in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Im implementing crystal report which is builtin in visual studio 2008. When i create my crystal report and check its preview it shows me the data but when i call it on my abc.aspx page report doesnt load and gives error 'Load report failed'.
This is my Code

```
 <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" 
            AutoDataBind="true" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" />
        <br />
    <br />
    <br />
        <br />
        <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server">
            <Report FileName="Reports/DailyPaymentStatus.rpt">
            </Report>
        </CR:CrystalReportSource>
```

what may be im doing wrong. This report also accept 4 parameters and im not setting them anywhere. Also one thing i want to mention if i make another simple project and do the same thing it runs perfectly and give me the output.

Comment: Is the folder 'Reports' in the same folder as the abc.aspx file?

Comment: Yes. I found out the answer the problem is with the path
 <Report FileName="Reports/DailyPaymentStatus.rpt">
it has to be like
 <Report FileName="~/Reports/DailyPaymentStatus.rpt">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I found out the answer the problem is with the path

```
<Report FileName="Reports/DailyPaymentStatus.rpt">
```

it has to be like

```
<Report FileName="~/Reports/DailyPaymentStatus.rpt">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call show data on report in DataBinding and Navigate methods.

```
protected void CrystalReportViewer1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ShowReportData();
}  

protected void CrystalReportViewer1_Navigate(object source,  CrystalDecisions.Web.NavigateEventArgs e)
{
    this.ShowReportData();
}
```